# c++ windows service -main entry point - how to debug

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, service

I created a service for Windows using a complete example found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540476(VS.85).aspx.

I do not know if it is the best example. A lot of people say Microsoft's examples are not the best. But it works. I can install, start, stop and delete the service without problems.

But now I need to effectively put the part of the code that should be what the service will do.

Reading the code I understood that this part creates a list and in it is placed the main of the service:

```
// TO_DO: Add any additional services for the process to this table.
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY DispatchTable[] = 
    { 
        { SVCNAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION) SvcMain }, 
        { NULL, NULL } 
    }; 

    // This call returns when the service has stopped. 
    // The process should simply terminate when the call returns.

    if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcher( DispatchTable )) 
    { 
        SvcReportEvent(TEXT("StartServiceCtrlDispatcher")); 
    }
```

If I understood correctly when the service was started the SvcMain function would be executed.

```
// Purpose: 
//   Entry point for the service
//
// Parameters:
//   dwArgc - Number of arguments in the lpszArgv array
//   lpszArgv - Array of strings. The first string is the name of
//     the service and subsequent strings are passed by the process
//     that called the StartService function to start the service.
// 
// Return value:
//   None.
//
VOID WINAPI SvcMain( DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR *lpszArgv )
{
    // Register the handler function for the service
LOGD << "passing 1";
    gSvcStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler( 
        SVCNAME, 
        SvcCtrlHandler);
LOGD << "passing 2";
    if( !gSvcStatusHandle )
    { 
        SvcReportEvent(TEXT("RegisterServiceCtrlHandler")); 
        return; 
    } 

    // These SERVICE_STATUS members remain as set here
LOGD << "passing 3";
    gSvcStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS; 
    gSvcStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;    

    // Report initial status to the SCM
LOGD << "passing 4";
    ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_START_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 3000 );

    // Perform service-specific initialization and work.
LOGD << "passing 5";
    SvcInit( dwArgc, lpszArgv );
}
```

I put log messages on multiple lines and I did not get any results. Nothing was recorded in the log file.

Log messages work during the service installation, but nothing is logged from within the SvcMain function.

Note:: Everything has been tested and works fine when run as a program, including in Debug.

1 - Is this function that executes the service code?
2 - Is it possible to write a log file from within a service?
3 - What other option would I have to debug inside the service?

Comment: This is essentially the same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44374566/1889329).

Comment: I agree, and you must agree that there was no useful suggestion beyond that which I should debug by running the application on the console. And then no more decent suggestions. I looked up everything there was about services and the only smarter answer I came across was that it was a hell of a hell to debug services because the Dispatcher Table is not instantiated unless the service is running. So now I've been a bit more specific, explained the problem and I'm asking for suggestions exactly on how not to debug but get returns of some sort.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that your log entries are remaining in the C run-time cache and never getting written to disk.  If in doubt, one way to confirm whether a particular piece of code is actually running is to add a call to RaiseException, i.e., deliberately crash the process.

Comment: Alternatively, put in a nice big Sleep() so that you can attach the debugger to the process while it is sleeping.  (There are probably better solutions, but I can't bring them to mind at the moment.)

Comment: Thank you Harry Johnston, I will try.